# Antivirus flagged dart.exe as ransomware

Tags: flutter

I was trying to setup flutter when my antivirus detected dart.exe as ransomware... I downloaded the package from the git repository using the documentation command line. Should I give it the permission or delete and download the zip?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same thing happen with my generated build. I just ignored it.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the MD5 or SHA-1 checksum of what you've downloaded with the values they provide. Then you can know for sure that they came from the correct source. (IF they provide one)

See this answer for info of how to verify
https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/189000/how-to-verify-the-checksum-of-a-downloaded-file-pgp-sha-etc

In general, just double check you're downloading from the correct domain. (Are you sure you're on github.com, is your connection secured? etc.)

General antivirus programs are cautious about downloading .exe files from the internet. (as they should be)